# How does sending function prototype to template works?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to understand how does `std::packaged_task` implemented in c++11 .

I write a simple class :

```
template<typename _Signature>
  class package;
template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
  class package<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>
  {

  };
int main()
{
    package<int(int,int)> a;
}
```

**My Question is :**

When we send `int(int,int)` as a template parameter, what type does compiler deduce ? What is `_Res`'s type in this example ? Is it `lambda` or `std::function` or something else ?

And what is the type of `_Res(_ArgTypes...)` ?

before c++11 we didn't have something like `int(int,int)`, How is it possible in c++11 ?

Comment: Shouldn't `int(int,int)` be `int(*)(int,int)`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ see example of this site : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task

Comment: `int(int, int)` is just a function type (not function pointer, as is more common). [That was definitely there before C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a7172d9ac8e243e). As a different example, `void foo(int bar(int)) {return bar(2);}`. The thing that changed in C++11 was that you can now use variadic templates to accept and extract any number of parameters in that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is odd as the compiler does not have to *deduce* a type for `int(int,int)`, it *is* a type itself. A function type to be precise. And this is nothing new in C++11, it existed in C++98 as well. Note that there is a difference between a function type and a type which is a pointer or reference to a function type:

```
#include <type_traits>

int foo( int, int )
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    using F = int(int,int);
    F* f1 = &foo;
    F& f2 = foo;
    f1( 1, 2 );
    f2( 2, 3 );

    static_assert( std::is_same< decltype(foo), int(int,int) >::value, "Oops" );
    static_assert( std::is_same< decltype(&foo), int(*)(int,int) >::value, "Oops" );
    static_assert( std::is_same< decltype(*&foo), int(&)(int,int) >::value, "Oops" );

    static_assert( ! std::is_same< decltype(foo), int(*)(int,int) >::value, "Oops" );
    static_assert( ! std::is_same< decltype(foo), int(&)(int,int) >::value, "Oops" );
}
```

In your example, the specialization has to deduce `_Res` and `_ArgTypes` where `_Res` is the result type of the function type (`int`) and `_ArgTypes` is a parameter pack with two types (both `int`) deduced from the argument list of the function type.

Comment: tnx I didn't know int(int,int) is a type. :)

Comment: @xyz it is a type, but it is a type that cannot be instantiated as a variable of that type.  Sort of like `void` cannot be.

Comment: @Yakk ALthough it can be used to declare a function, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/418211d0f39113b4).

Comment: @danielfrey or a method even.